# Printer setup problem

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

Using Ubuntu 12.04 on old used to be XP desktop now dedicated to Ubuntu. Printer is Canon MX320. Had been running it on my other desktop and laptop thru a switch. No problem. Want to eliminate the Win7 box and use the Linux and the Canon printer. Unable to print anything. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

I get to localhost:631, add printer and asks for my username, put it in, then password but it does not recognize it. ?? just reverts back to the ask username/password box.

---

OK I got through the login but it could not find my printer (MX320). All it found was similar models as PIXMA 300, 330. Thay did not work. It did show up in the print queue but no activity.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I did use CUPS but the problem was with that I was going through an IO Gear printer switch. When I connected the computer directly to the printer, it worked. So now I am looking for a USB cable that has two true Y male ends if that's possible so I can attach my other computer to the printer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to configure the printer through CUPS?

You can access the interface by web browser - localhost:631.

Choose "Adding Printer and Classes".